# How do I add a string to .attr('', '') value

Tags: jquery, attr, sign

I would like to add a value with this signs
`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '', '', '']);`

`.attr('', '`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '', '', '']);`')`

how do I print that into the variable into the attribute?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: please review your question, it is unreadable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make the value of `_gaq.push(...)` the value of a specific attribute.  If so then just do the following

```
.attr('theName', _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '', '', '']) + '');
```